# Backing Bean Map property, issue with types

Tags: jsf, generics, dictionary, el

In the JSF application I am working on, we used to have a field for a money amount. In the backing bean, the type for this property was BigDecimal:

```
<h:inputText id="amount" name="amount" value="#{backingBean.amount}" required="false"/>
```

And the backing Bean:

```
public class backingBean {
    //...
    BigDecimal amount;
    //...
}
```

Now, we introduced a change so from now on we have a variable number of input fields for amounts.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{backingBean.participations}" var="participation" varStatus="status">    
   <h:inputText id="amount" name="amount" value="#{backingBean.amounts[participation.id]}" required="false"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

And the backing bean:

```
public class backingBean {
    //...
    Map<Long, BigDecimal> amounts;
    //...
}
```

This work almost fine, but after submit the form, the type of the entries inside the map amounts are `<Object, Object>` instead of `<Long, BigDecimal>`, as you can see on the snapshot grabbed from the debugger:

[image]

This gives an error when try to perform any operation with the map.

As a workaround, I've changed the type of the map to be `Map<Long, String>` and provided a getter `public Map<Long, BigDecimal> getAmounts()` that converts the map, but I would like to keep it simpler.

- Am I doing something wrong here?
- Is it a known JSF bug?
- Any ideas to get this working with the minimal amount of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At runtime, the generic type of your map is erased.  As a consequence, JSF has no way to know that the type of your map value is BigDecimal.  This causes it to handle the values as generic objects, for which the default is a String converter.  So when rendering the page, the value's toString is shown.  When it is resubmitted the value is entered as a String in the map.

You can ignore the `<Object, Object>` you see in the debugger, it is of no consequence.

You should instead specify that the input should use a bigdecimal converter.  That should solve your issue.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{backingBean.participations}" var="participation" varStatus="status">    
   <h:inputText id="amount" name="amount" value="#{backingBean.amounts[participation.id]}" required="false">
    <f:converter converterId="javax.faces.BigDecimal"/>
  </h:inputText>
</ui:repeat>
```